# Calculating acceleration of a car going downhill

Tags: homework-and-exercises, acceleration

Let's say a car is driving down a hill. Throughout the descent, you have access to the car's speedometer, a stop watch, and GPS altitude readings. You also know the car's mass if that helps. How would you go about calculating the portion the car's acceleration generated by the work of only its engine? In other words, I know that gravity is contributing to the acceleration but I want to know how much the engine is contributing to the acceleration. Thanks for any help that you can provide!

Comment: what have you done towards solving this problem yourself?

Comment: Hi Jimself. I haven't taken physics since high school and I remembered drawing force diagrams so a started with that before asking this question. That felt more complicated than it needed to be and I had a vague recollection there was a simple solution if you ignore friction and stuff like that so i figured I'd ask the pros. The law of conservation of energy is exactly what I was trying but failing to remember so I'm very appreciative for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gets a little complicated, at least for high precision.

As a really simple first version, you can assume no frictional losses. No aerodynamic drag, either. Then, starting at the top of the hill, measure the car's speed and calculate its kinetic energy. At the bottom of the hill (with a height h), measure the speed again and calculate the kinetic energy. Call these $v_1$ and $v_2$, and of course the mass of the car is m.

Then the excess energy E provided by the engine is $$E = \frac{m {v_2}^2}{2} - \frac{m {v_1}^2}{2} - mgh$$

That is, in dropping a distance h, a body will convert potential energy mgh to kinetic energy.

So much for simple. If you want accuracy, you'll need to calculate how much energy your car loses simply by moving. You'll need to take into account rolling friction of the tires, wind resistance, and frictional losses in the wheel bearings (although you can almost certainly fold that into the rolling friction term). This can be done by taking your car out on a perfectly flat and horizontal stretch of road, cranking up your speed to an appropriate number, then putting the car in neutral. Then make a detailed record of speed vs time as the car slows down. Converting the speed to kinetic energy will give you a curve which expresses energy vs time, and the slope of the curve can be used to derive instantaneous energy loss rate (power) as a function of speed. If you're lucky and good, you can convert this to an elegant function of power vs speed.

With this, you can take your speedo readings and calculate the energy lost to simply moving, and include this in your calculation.

Comment: Thanks so much! I haven't taken physics in a while and this was a great reminder about conservation of energy. So if I understand correctly, had this been a box on wheels instead of a car (closed system), E would be zero. But it's not a closed system so E is the energy added.

Comment: @7luckyseven7 - Well, maybe not. For instance, if the car is in low gear, it may serve as a brake, in which case E is negative. If the throttle is adjusted precisely to maintain the vehicle speed as it would be in a zero-friction environment, the result of the equation will be zero. That, however, does not account for the energy required to keep the engine running while doing no work. It's important to keep track of just exactly what is considered part of the system.

Answer (score 0):

It is not as sophisticated as it looks like first take the speed of the car at the end of the slope $v_1$ so the overall energy of the object would be $E = \frac{1}{2}mv_1^2$. Assuming that at the start the car has no kinetic energy.

Now we simply remove the gravitational potential from it, so:
$W = \frac{1}{2}mv^2 - mgh$ Then to find the velocity the engine we can substitute $W$ for $\frac{1}{2}mv_2^2$ which gives us:

$$\frac{1}{2}mv_2^2=\frac{1}{2}mv_1^2 - mgh$$

We can solve for $v_2$ like so:

$mv_2^2 = mv_1^2 - 2mgh$

$v_2^2 = v_1^2 - 2gh$

$v_2 = \sqrt{v_1^2 - 2gh}$